# How to display python result in a specific html tag?

Tags: python, html

I want to display my python result into a specific HTML tag on a site. How can I do that?

My code to get the results :

```
# To print All cases for all countries in from all past days in EU.
Cases = sum(map(lambda x: int(x['cases']), json.loads(data)['records']))
print(Cases)

# To print All deaths for all countries in from all past days in EU.

Deaths = sum(map(lambda x: int(x['deaths']), json.loads(data)['records']))
print(Deaths)
```

The result :

```
31397816
701325
```

The html code :

```
            <h2 class="u-custom-font u-text u-text-black u-text-font u-text-1">Total Active Cases</h2>
                      <h3 class="u-text u-text-2" data-animation-name="counter" data-animation-event="scroll" data-animation-duration="3000" style="will-change: contents;">63</h3>
                      <a href="Cases.html#sec-f85d" data-page-id="181623978" class="u-btn u-btn-rectangle u-button-style u-palette-1-base u-btn-1">learn more</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="u-size-30">
                <div class="u-layout-row">
                  <div class="u-container-style u-layout-cell u-left-cell u-size-30 u-layout-cell-3">
                    <div class="u-container-layout u-container-layout-3">
                      <h2 class="u-align-left u-custom-font u-text u-text-custom-color-3 u-text-font u-text-3">
                        <span style="font-weight: 700;" class="u-text-black">Total Closed Cases</span>
                        <br>
                      </h2>
                      <h3 class="u-align-center u-text u-text-4" data-animation-name="counter" data-animation-event="scroll" data-animation-duration="3000" style="will-change: contents;">57842</h3>
                      <a href="Cases.html#sec-f85d" data-page-id="181623978" class="u-btn u-btn-rectangle u-button-style u-palette-1-base u-btn-2">learn more</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Results should apper in `<h3 class="u-text u-text-2"` and `<h3 class="u-align-center u-text u-text-4"`

Comment: Are you going to show us the input data?

Comment: You must use a backend framework to do that. As you coded in Python, Flask should be your most obvious choice [https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)